# Unit test custom IActionResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext) in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Having the below class

```
/// <summary>
/// An unsuccessful HTTP result.
/// </summary>
public class UnsuccessfulActionResult : IActionResult, IHttpStatusCodeResult, IErrors
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    /// The HTTP status code.
    /// </summary>
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The corresponding error messages, if any.
    /// </summary>
    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Errors { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The request Transaction ID.
    /// </summary>
    public string TransactionId { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default ctor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="transactionId">The request Transaction ID.</param>
    /// <param name="errors">The corresponding error messages, if any.</param>
    /// <param name="httpStatusCode"></param>
    public UnsuccessfulActionResult(
        string transactionId,
        HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode,
        IReadOnlyCollection<string> errors = null)
    {
        TransactionId = transactionId;
        StatusCode = httpStatusCode;
        Errors = errors ?? new List<string>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convenient method to create an unsuccessful response model.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="statusCode"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected UnsuccessfulResponseModel CreateResponseModel(int statusCode)
    {
        return new UnsuccessfulResponseModel(TransactionId, statusCode, Errors);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public virtual Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var objectResult = new ObjectResult(CreateResponseModel((int)StatusCode))
        {
            StatusCode = (int)StatusCode
        };

        return objectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }
}
```

I need to test this class to make sure that ActionContext has the response provided in overridden ExecuteResultAsync.

Just started going deep into ASP.NET Core 2.0 and missing some parts, in Web API 2 I would just check the HttpResponseMessage returned in the equivalent method of `IHttpActionResult`.

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(
    CancellationToken cancellationToken
)
```

Comment: I am trying to do this sociably via the controller in unit test.  I am having a horrible time with this.  The only thing I can think now is to use TestServer or Out out of process test.  Did you come to a solution ?

Comment: Still didn't find an appropriate way to do this. MS sometimes sucks big time.

Comment: I took 2 approaches.  I created a custom action result and was able to test it by basically calling execute async.  Id have to give you a code sample, but it felt mental.   The other...I used the compat shim so I could use HttpResponseMessage and the HttpResponseMesssageOutputFormatter (from memory so might not be remembering properly)  yeah its a retrogade step, but I dropped unit tests entirely, as it just works...

Comment: I had other coverage though.